# Android Things - Raspberry Pi 3 B - adb install apk - INSTALL FAILED OLDER SDK

Tags: android, adb, android-things

I have a custom build of Android Things with my app sdk successfully installed on my RP 3B. I wanted to update the apk with a new version so I'm attempting to install it via adb.

I get the following error when trying to install: `INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK`

[image]

Now, this seems pretty self explanatory, the APK is built using API 27, not API 28. The issue is that it IS build with API 28.

[image]

I've removed all traces of API 27 and this is still happening.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change from 28 to 27 for **miniSdkVersion**

```
miniSdkVersion 27
```

**Explanation**:

`miniSdkVersion` is the minimal required Android version that your apk can run on. If you set it to 28, then it won't be able to install on device with Android 27.

Comment: That worked.  Thanks!  I suppose I don't understand why the error would suggest I'm using an older sdk.

I was to understand that Android Things was 27+, so targeting with min of 28 should be fine.  Either way, I get it now.  Thanks again!

Comment: @AnxGotta Android Things as an SDK may work with a `minSdkVersion` of 28, but that error message is about your device, which is running on API 27.

Comment: I see.  So the Android Things installation (v1.0.6.5092020) on the RP3B is version 27.  This is what I didn't understand!  Thanks @TheWanderer